The indicator that paints on the chart of equal prices is consistent with the specified interval in the parameters
Tell me how it is possible to implement (or perhaps you already know such a solution is ready) an indicator that will be added to the chart according to individual parameters for which chart the price is equal to a multiple of the time specified in the parameters. For example, for Bitcoin, if you enter 5000 in the parameters, then the equals will be visually marked on the chart as ...65000, 60000, 55000, 50000...
